# Keeping a binary search tree by splitting nodes (like a B-Tree)

Tags: data-structures, binary-trees, search-trees, database-theory, balanced-search-trees

A B-tree is kept balanced (i.e. all leaves at same depth) by splitting a node when adding a child that won't fit, and propagating this splitting up to the root.

Can the same technique be used to keep a regular binary search tree balanced (since a binary search tree can be viewed as a 2 child maximum B-tree)? If so, does that rebalancing method have a name, and what are its advantages/disadvantages to other ways of keeping a BST balanced, such as Red-Black trees?

Comment: In a sense, red-black trees do work on precisely that principle. (The sense is that red-black trees are just an alternative way to implement 2-3-4 trees.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. A "regular binary search tree" doesn't have any balancing mechanism; as soon as you add such a mechanism, it's not a regular binary search tree" any more -- it's a something-something balanced binary search tree.

Comment: Red-black trees are one way of building (abstract) 2-3 trees, essentially B-trees with at most 3 children for each node.

Answer (score 2):

[1-2 Brother Trees, as in "Purely Functional 1-2 Brother Trees" by Ralf Hinze](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/ralf.hinze/publications/Brother12.pdf) in some way allow splitting a node. Like in 2-4 trees where nodes have 2 to 4 children, in 1-2 brother trees, nodes have 1 to 2 children.

The advantages are a bit hand-wavey: it is sometimes faster, and sometimes simpler, and sometimes uses less space.